# How to pass a comma ',' character to ACTION_DIAL intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I  would like to be  able to pass commas ',' into an Action_dial intent. A comma is used for a pause when  pressing numbers for an automated phone menu system.
These can  be  placed in numbers  in Contacts and it will work fine but when  trying to Parse or Encode a URI to pass this into the Action_Dial intent, it passes the  number in right up  until the  ',' and then will not pass anything  after the  ','.

I  have  tried several different ways  of doing this several different ways.
Such as...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:14051234567,,3,1"));
startActivity(intent)
```

and..

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.fromParts("tel", "14051234567", ","));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

and

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("14051234567")+ Uri.encode(",")));
```

and every other way that I've found here on StackOverflow.

Is there a way to make this happen?

EDIT-
Maybe this can't be made to work?? I  just ran  across this Android Bug report that was closed by Google but not ever fixed. Lame Google.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7993

Comment: How about backslash then comma... "\,"

Comment: @Sheychan   Thanks for the  suggestion but that code will not compile. It says  "illegal escape sequence in  string literal".  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:14051234567\,3")));

Comment: It seems dependent on android version. The code with exaclty ',' in phone passed to dialler works perfectly on one device and doesn't work on another.

Comment: here is generic document of tel Uri : https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt
It not specific about android but, it has lot of information about tel Uri.